# Comparing different binding agents (Konjac, Xanthan Gum, Guar Gum, Corn Flour)

Tags: baking

Is there any way to figure out the potency of different binding agents, such as: Konjac, Xanthan Gum, Guar Gum, Corn Flour, before purchasing them?

Comment: What do you mean by "potency"? Are you thinking of this as a relative measure of how different binding agents perform (like xanthan vs. guar gum)? Or as a means of sampling *a specific batch* of any given binding agent, prior to purchasing in bulk?

Comment: Konjac? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjac Interesting, hadn't heard of that one. Don't forget tapioca starch. Looking for something like "gel test konjac" with konjac replaced with the agent of your choosing will probably be helpful: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=gel+test+konjac&t=ffsb&ia=web

Comment: ...not sure I would consider xanthan or guar "binding agents".  What is your goal?

Comment: By potency I mean how they compare to each other relative to a specific property, which in this case is how well they bind together materials such as oil and water. Thanks!

Comment: I want to know how much Xanthan Gum to use in replacement of Konjac

Comment: Xanthan generally produces slime of increasing thickness with percent. If you want an edible product with reasonable mouth feel, I'd go with Guar, gelatin, agar, corn flour, even rice starch before inflicting 5% Xanthan gum on people. Often mixtures of different agents are best. You need to experiment to see what's best for your application. There are books with titles like "Polysaccharide Association Structures in Food" but you'd best live near a University with a good Food Science department to access them as they are quite expensive to buy. BTW "bind oil and water" = emulsifier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with cornflour being used as a binding agent, but as a thickener or as a key ingredient in things like Turkish Delight as a gelling agent. When cooked it releases starch which gels things up.

Xanthan and guar gums are used as a substitute for gluten in flour blends that cater for coeliacs and other sufferers. Since they replicate gluten's role in baking it's safe to say that they're quite sticky when wet.